# Magento 2 : Show and hide field in custom payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment, html, knockoutjs

In my custom payment method there is 1 checkbox as seen below:

[image]

In the Admin Settings, if I set it to disable then I don't want to show it.

Following div is for that field.

*form.html*

```
<div class="payfull_form-group use-3d-wrapper" style="">
    <div class="custom-input">
      <div class="custom-checkbox">
        <label class="custom-label empty-payfull_label"></label>
        <label class="custom-label_checkbox">
          <input name="use3d" id="use3d" value="1" type="checkbox">
          Use 3D secure Payments System
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How about your issue now?

Comment: Solved thanks for helping me.
I have created helper file and config file.
In config file I have used helper because there i have defined my function.
Thanks again

Comment: If my answer helped you solving your problem, please accept it as the solution.

Comment: I have accepted
In first part of code u define function get3DSecure()
Which is not working for me.

Comment: You have used the Js and html logic?

Comment: Yes That was really very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already the payment, you can follow the same logic:

In your Payment Config Provider, you add the 3D Secure config:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getConfig()
{
    return $this->method->isAvailable() ? [
        'payment' => [
            'your_payment_code' => [
                ......
                '3DSecure' => $this->get3DSecure()
            ],
        ],
    ] : [];
}
/**
* Get config from admin
*/
public function get3DSecure()
{
    //Data from system.xml fields
    return $this->getConfigData('3dsecure');
}
```

Navigate to the Js payment method render, we can get from checkout global variable:

```
/*browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'YourModule_Payment/payment/custompayment'
            },

            get3DSecure: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.paymentcustom.3DSecure;
            },

            isEnable3DSecure: function() {
              if(this.get3DSecure()) {
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }

        });
    }
);
```

In your html template, we can check:

```
      <!-- ko if: isEnable3DSecure() -->
            <div class="payfull_form-group use-3d-wrapper" style="">
                <div class="custom-input">
                    <div class="custom-checkbox">
                        <label class="custom-label empty-payfull_label"></label>
                        <label class="custom-label_checkbox">
                        <input name="use3d" id="use3d" value="1" type="checkbox">
                        Use 3D secure Payments System
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
```

Read more: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html

Comment: I have not created any Payment Config Provider.
Please tell me where and why we have to create.

Comment: Which tutorial you follow to create a custom payment?

Comment: I don't remember now.

Comment: Now, you payment can show? Can you update you answer with the payment folder structure? You can use this tool to generate your payment: http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module

Comment: Right I have created with this tool already.
Yes, my payment method is showing at checkout page.

Comment: \Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\Pendingpayment.php
\Model\Custom.php
These 2 files are there
In which file i have to make changes

Comment: So, I think your payment should have a Config Provider?

Comment: Yes, I am new in Magento Developement.
Plese tell me Why we have to create config file and tell location of that file to add above functions.
I understood about 2nd and 3rd block of code in your answer but not 1st.

Comment: Ah! I have just take a look, the generated payment didn't have the Config Provider.

Comment: You should follow the guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html#access-the-system-config-data

Comment: Ok. I will follow it and then I will tell you status.

Comment: Getting that error when I am trying to get config value
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Nitesh\Payment\Helper\Paymentapi does not exist

Comment: @Nitesh where you call the helper Payment Api?

Comment: My error is solved